# Quartz - schedule jobs every two Weeks regardless of the start time

Tags: quartz-scheduler

What is the cron expression for the following schedule :

Monday and Tuesday at 8:00 am, every 2 weeks.

Can we define "Every 3 weeks" regardless of the the start time ? (I don't care if it's every 3 weeks starting from the first week of the month or year, I want to run it for 5 years and literally every 3 weeks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find a cron expression that meets your schedule.
For example [this howto](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/cookbook/BiWeeklyTrigger.html) states, that:

> You need a SimpleTrigger or CalendarIntervalTrigger to schedule
>   biweekly fire points.

I think you need two Simple Triggers to define a schedule like *"Monday and Tuesday at 8:00 am every 2 weeks"*, namely one biweekly trigger for each monday, and just like that one biweekly trigger for each tuesday.

Similarly you could tackle the *"Every 3 weeks"* problem.